# SciFi book from an alien's perspective

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a SciFi book I came across when I was a kid (25+ years ago) which starts out with a scene where the narrator describes seeing these "aliens" who are tall and hairless except for a tuft of hair on the tops of their heads.  Quickly it is clear that the narrator is the native of another planet describing first seeing humans as they visit its planet.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like the Tines' first impression of humans in Vernor Vinge's *A Fire Upon the Deep* (1992), Chapter 4: *...they got their first view of the visitor from heaven, or part of him anyway. There were four legs per member, but it walked on its rear legs only. What a clown! Yet…it used its front paws for holding things. Not once did he see it use a mouth; he doubted if the flat jaws could get a good hold, anyway.*

Comment: However, the reader already knows that the description in *A Fire Upon the Deep* is from an alien point of view, so I think it probably isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might be able to remember more details to [edit] into your question if you review the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407).

Comment: Yeah, it's not that uncommon a trope in SF novels to see humans first from an alien perspective, so any other details you can remember would be helpful (particularly anything you can remember about the actual aliens and how they were different).

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumansThroughAlienEyes might be helpful (warning, TV Tropes link!)

Comment: It sounds like any number of Clifford Simak stories.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly [The Asses of Balaam](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55519) by Randall Garrett. This was published in 1961 so you could have read it 25 years ago. [It is available on Project Gutenberg here](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/30583).

The tag line is:

> A twenty-four legged ecologist is alarmed by a subordinate's report of bipedal animals suddenly appearing and despoiling the surface of the planet. It must be a hoax.

The mysterious bipedal animals are of course humans, though I don't think this is explicitly mentioned anywhere in the story (the story uses the term *human* to refer to the narrator's race). The specific quote you are thinking of is:

> Their locomotive limbs ended in lumpy protuberances that showed no sign of toes, and they were covered all over with a dull gray hide, except for the hands at the ends of their handling limbs and the necks and the faces of their oddly-shaped heads, where the skin ranged in color from a pinkish an to a definitive brown, depending on the individual. There was no hair anywhere on their bodies except on the top and back of their heads. No, wait--there were two long tufts above each eye.

Answer (score 2):

This could be John Scalzi's *[The Ghost Brigades](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Ghost_Brigades/0H2ujnLIb4YC?hl=en&gbpv=0)*, second book of his *Old Man's War* series.

> *But now the differences emerge*, thought Cainen, as the creature barked at him again: A broader torso
>   and abdominal plain, and a generally awkward skeletal structure and musculature. Stump-like feet; clublike hands. Outwardly obvious sexual differentiation (this one in front of him was female, if he
>   remembered correctly). Compromised sensory input thanks to only two small optical and aural inputs
>   rather than the optical and aural bands that wrapped nearly entirely around Cainen's head. Fine
>   keratinous fibers on the head rather than heat-radiating skin folds. Not for the first time, Cainen reflected
>   that evolution didn't do this particular species any great favors, physically speaking.
>
> It just made them aggressive, dangerous and damned hard to scrape off a planet surface. A problem, that.
>   The creature in front of Cainen jabbered at him again and pulled out a short, nasty-looking object.
>
> Cainen looked directly into the creature's optical inputs.
>   "Fucking humans," he said.

Possible contraindication, it was published in 2007, so it's only 12 years old.

Comment: Wow contraindication is such a fancy word I thought it was a typo of contradiction :P

Answer (score 2):

Gaultheria posted a comment suggesting Vernor Vinge's *[A Fire Upon the Deep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fire_Upon_the_Deep)*, which got an answer comment (maybe from the original querent), stating that that was it, so I'm posting it. This is a quote from Chapter 4 by the Tines, dog-like telepathic aliens:

> .... they got their first view of the visitor from heaven, or part of him anyway. There were four legs per member, but it walked on its rear legs only. What a clown! Yet…it used its front paws for holding things. Not once did he see it use a mouth; he doubted if the flat jaws could get a good hold, anyway.